# Add header in web.config conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, https, web-config

Is there any way to make exceptions from a custom headers rule in web.config?

I have the header X-Frame-Options in web.config, which adds it for all files.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I want to exclude a few pages from this rule in the controller.

I cannot remove the header in the controller since web.config adds it after the controller is executed.

I also don't want to remove the header from web.config and then instead add it in the controller or in an attribute for the controller for all pages, because that would only add it for HTML files returned by a controller, not static HTML files, js files, pictures and more.

I don't know of a way to make the adding of the header in web.config conditional, if there is perhaps I could add a temporary header in the controller, and then write something like

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    if(!header("allowembedding")){
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    }
    <remove name="allowembedding" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can make this work with the `<location>` element:

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->

  <location path="Path/To/Exclude">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.
I would like to remove it from the controller rather then hardcoding url/filepaths like this.
Removing it from the controller would let me remove x-frame-options based on anny condition, and without changing web.config for each file.
But this is better than nothing.

Comment: @Mabbus I can see the attraction in that, but `X-Frame-Options` is a security related header and it doesn't sound like a best-practice approach to decide on it's value within the business logic. I suggest reconsidering your security design and make clear-cut areas of your application that you want to allow iframing/embedding from instead.

Comment: If I could have removed the header in code I would have added the option to remove it in some specific page types that is not sensitive, so the editors dont accedentally remove it from logged in pages.

But your way is good enough and it worked (also for subpages under the specified path).
I did it for the /about urls on the webpage, and It will work as long as they dont change their urls.

If I had a slash in the begining of path I got an error.
Please remove the first slash in path in the answer so it does not misslead more people :)

Comment: @Mabbus You're right, I've removed it. Good to hear you made it work.